# Django Rest Framework Role and Permissions having hierarchical relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

We have two user types:

- service provide
- customer

each user has following roles-

- admin
- service and support
- operator
  -reporter

but each role has follwoing subrole
region admin, region operator, region service and support
and with same way to other roles
site admin, site operaotor , site service and support

in above case service provider and cusotmer has hierarchical relationship. service provider in top of customer.

then how to manges role and permission with hierarchical in efficent way ?
how to get data in hierarchial way ?

then how to manges role and permission with hierarchical in efficent way ?
how to get data in hierarchial way ?